# Java reflection and generics - parameterized type info missing "extends"

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I would like to reconstitute the signature of a method using reflection in Java 8.  I've run into some issues with generic methods.
In particular, I find nothing to help recover information about cases of "extends" or "super" in the template type declaration.

Here's a specific test case, based on known source code:

Signature of the method from source code:
`public static <T extends AssertDelegateTarget> T assertThat(T assertion)`

**First of all, is there an elegant way to reconstitute the `<T extends AssertDelegateTarget>` part without having to parse Strings?**

Here's the main info I was able to get by reflection:

- `method.toString()`:

  `public static org.assertj.core.api.AssertDelegateTarget org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat(org.assertj.core.api.AssertDelegateTarget)`
- `method.toGenericString()`:

  `public static <T> T org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat(T)`

  **What happened to "extends AssertDelegateTarget"?**
- `method.getReturnType.toString()`:

  `interface org.assertj.core.api.AssertDelegateTarget`
- `method.getGenericParameterTypes()[0].getTypeName()`:

  `T`

**Based on the above reflection info, I could assume a relationship between T and AssertDelegateTarget, but how do I know whether it's "extends" or "super"?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the `Method` object already.  Starting from here, get the type parameters that are declared on the method with [the `getTypeParameters` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getTypeParameters--), which returns a `TypeVariable<Method>[]`.  This is an array of the type parameter declared on the method.  In this case it has one type parameter, so the returned array has only one element.

The [`TypeVariable` interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/TypeVariable.html) has a method to retrieve the name `T`, `getName`, and a method to retrieve the bounds, `getBounds`.  The `getBounds` method returns a `Type[]`.  You can be sure that any bounds here are upper bounds, because the declarations of type variables aren't allowed to use `super`, only `extends`.

In this case, the `Type` variable is just the `Class` object for `AssertDelegateTarget`.

Now you can re-construct the `"<T extends AssertDelegateTarget>"` string from the above information.  Only use "extends" if the `Type[]` is non-empty.  If there were multiple bounds, you would place a comma in between them, e.g. `T extends Bound1, Bound2`.